# Advice on data structure for scaler operation between dictionary and dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dictionary of constants which needs to be multiplied to a data frame. Can any one provide guidance on how to handle this situation or suggest efficient data structure?

for example constant dictionary is like

```
dct = {a : [0.1,0.22,0.13],b : [0.544,0.65,0.17],c : [0.13,0.544,0.65]}
```

and then I have a dataframe.

```
d = {'ID': ['A1','A2','A3'],'AAA':[0,0.4,0.8],'AA':[0,0.6,0.1],'A':[0,0.72,0.32],'BBB':[0,0.55,0.66]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What I want to do is pick each constant from array and apply some complex function to a data frame based on condition. Could you advice me on data structure I should use?

I also thought about converting data frame to dictionary and then perform scaler operation using zip but that doesn't seem right. 
i.e.

```
 df2.set_index('ID').T.to_dict(orient='list')

for k,v in dct.items():
   for k1,v1 in df2_dct.items():
        #here I have two lists v and v1 to perform operation but this is not efficient.
```

operations are like if value is 0, ignore, if less then 0.5 than some formula, else if greater than 0.5 then some formula.

I'd appreciate any advice.

EDIT1:
Another Idea I have is to iterate through each key,value of dictionary 'dct' , add value list a dataframe column and then perform operation. It is totally doable and fast but then how do I store all 3 dataframes?

EDIT2:
Scaler operations are like:

```
tmp_list = list()
for i in range(len(v1)):
    if v1[i] ==0:
        temp_list[i]=v1[i]
    if v1[i]>0.5:
        temp_list[i]=v1[i]*4 + v[i]^2
   if v1[i] <0.5:
        temp_list[i]=v1[i]*0.24+v[i]
```

EDIT3:
expected output would be either dictionary or dataframe. In Case of dictionary, it will be a nested dictionary like,

```
op_dct = {'a':{'A1':[values],'A2':[values],'A3':[values]},
          'b':{'A1':[values],'A2':[values],'A3':[values]},
          'c':{'A1':[values],'A2':[values],'A3':[values]} }
```

so that I can access vector like op_dct[constant_type][ID].

multiple dataframes doesn't seem right option.

Comment: why `dct = {a : [0.1,0.22,0.13],b : [0.544,0.65,0.17],a : [0.13,0.544,0.65]}`?

Comment: @ansev because each a,b,c define different characteristic. and this is all part of parameters pre-computations before actual model takes place so I want to keep it as light processing as possible

Comment: what exactly the operation you want to do with `v` and `v1`? Some sort of `broadcasting` might help.

Comment: @QuangHoang Edited Question with example operations between v and v1,

Comment: @QuangHoang This temp_list is just a row of dataframe and it is very costly operation(n^3) due to 3 nested for loops. 2 from iterating over each dictionary and dataframe , 1 from iterating over values of row.

Comment: This looks very vectorizable without going through all the for loop. You should attach your expected output from the sample data.

Comment: @QuangHoang Added output expectation. To me, 3 for loops are unavoidable to generate the output vector.